# Running Spark with Java 6

Tags: command-line, system-installation, apache2, java, javafx

I'm stuck at this stage. I am trying to install [Spark](http://sparkjava.com). 
I installed Java 6 and Scala 2.11.6. Installing Spark displays the error shown below:

`Exception in thread hand java.lang.unsepporttedclassversionerror`

[image: java scala error]

Comment: Are you sure you should be running the app with Java 6? That error implies the need for a newer version of Java. (For reference, Java 9 is out right now)

Answer (score 3):

"Unsupported class version" implies that the Java classes you're trying to run are of a version that's too new for your Java runtime. [Spark's website](http://sparkjava.com/download.html) confirms that it's not compatible with Java 7 or older, so it's no wonder that you get this error trying to run it on Java 6. Install Java 8 and you should have more success.

From your comment, it seems that you think Scala requires Java 6. This is untrue. The Scala [website](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/) says:

> The Scala software distribution can be installed on any platform with a Java runtime, version **1.6 or later**. Scala 2.12 **requires Java 8**.

(My emphasis.)

Comment: I have already installed java and scala 8 does not support this version so I try java 6 please recommend me a version of scala which adapts with a version of java

Comment: @Pont Please, post your answer to the original question. This one it's an exact duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/819350/how-tion-install-java6 It is very possible that the current one will be deleted due to duplication.

Comment: then I have to install java scala 2.12 with 8

Comment: (I smell a "duel" between "twins"...)

Comment: @CristianaNicolae OP appears to have deleted the other question, so I will leave my answer here.

Comment: i delete publication cristiana

Comment: Interesting! The so-called duplicate was posted first, so it was older than the current question.  But that one had no answer while this one has. So, as I observe now, it had no priority over this one. Looks like, sometimes, it's not a matter of time, but a matter of substance.

Comment: @lyly So it was your action?! I thought that it was a moderator intervention (It's almost 2 AM here, my focus is low). And it was the reasoning that puzzled me. Now I see that you've erased it. Good! This was AskUbuntu is kept clean and well organized. :-)

Comment: Im sorry  for confusion I'm new here I really mastering the English language

Comment: please can you help me to  Install a correct version of Java that fits with Scala

Comment: @lyly I am afraid that I am not the person to help you with this. In fact, right now, your expertize in this matter is higher than mine. :-) But I can suggest you to look on our sister-site StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/ I saw that there are questions about the Java/Scala matter on it. Also, keep an eye on the bugs: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/scala/+bugs Good luck! :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44780/discussion-between-cristiana-nicolae-and-lyly).